# Statistics question using multiplication rule

Tags: statistics

my question is:

**The Neckware Association of America reported that 2.5% of ties sold in the United States are bow ties. Suppose three people who bought ties are randomly selected, what is the probability that they bought a bow tie**

I try to use the Multiplication rule and probability of at least one rule, and I can't seem to get it:

**So let P(B) = 2.5% = .025, so P(all 3) = (.025)^3 = 0.000015625
P(none of the 3 ties are bow ties) = (.975) ^ 3 = .9269
So if at least one of them is a bow tie, wouldn't it be 1 - P(none of the 3 ties are bow ties) = 1 -.9269 = .07314**

However, that does not seem to be the right answer.

Comment: It should be clarified what exactly is meant by "what is the probability *that they* bought a bow tie."  Does this mean we are interested in the probability that at least one of them bought a bow tie, or are we interested in the probability that all three bought a bow tie?  In either case you calculated both and calculated both correctly.  The only errors I see is that you rounded instead of using exact numbers, opting to round to five decimal points on some and four decimal points on others.

Comment: I assume it means one bow tie, the wording is unclear and that is the question as it is given to me.

Comment: Well... if you are interested in exactly one bow tie, then just use the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) to see that it would be $3\cdot (0.025)\cdot (0.975)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

The wording of the question is misleading, as it doesn't say if ALL of them brought a tie, or just one of them. Your maths is correct however

Comment: I agree, the wording is misleading but sadly that is how the question is given to me.